# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'menu.addEventListener')

Tags: javascript

У меня в работе FullStack проект. Раньше работал исключительно с Python и Django, сейчас подключил и JavaScript. Возникает проблема:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'menu.addEventListener')
```

Примечательно то, что эта проблема только в проекте Django. Когда я подключаю scripts.js в обычную html страницу вне проекта - код работает как надо. В Django же проблема. Не понимаю, почему она возникает, особенно, когда задокументировал весь код в файле scripts.js, а она всё равно отображается в консоле разработчика. Очищал кэш браузера, не знаю, как решить. На данный момент ни один скрипт не работает в проекте.

Вот как он подключён:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Сайт парфюмерии</title>
    <script src="{% static 'main_application/js/scripts.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main_application/css/style.css' %}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Вот html дерево, где должен работать скрипт:

```
<ul class="buttons-section" id="mouse-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="" class="sign-in" data-context="login">Войти</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="" class="reg" data-context="reg">Зарегистрироваться</a>
    </li>
    <hr>
</ul>
```

И сам скрипт:

```
const menu = document.querySelector("#mouse-menu");
const dropDownMenu = document.getElementById("drop-down");
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

menu.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    dropDownMenu.style.display = "block";
    dropDownMenu.style.zIndex = "1";
    dropDownMenu.style.backgroundColor = "#fafafa";
});

dropDownMenu.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    dropDownMenu.style.display = "none";
});

menu.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    dropDownMenu.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, скрипт отрабатывает быстрее, чем загрузился DOM. Попробуйте обернуть весь код в слушатель события **DOMContentLoaded**(Подробнее о [DOMContentLoaded](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded))

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector("#mouse-menu");
    const dropDownMenu = document.getElementById("drop-down");
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    menu.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      dropDownMenu.style.display = "block";
      dropDownMenu.style.zIndex = "1";
      dropDownMenu.style.backgroundColor = "#fafafa";
    });

    dropDownMenu.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      dropDownMenu.style.display = "none";
    });

    menu.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      dropDownMenu.style.display = "none";
    });
  })
```

Если вам необходимо использовать переменные menu, dropDownMenu и body за пределами блока, то можно сделать так:

```
let menu;
  let dropDownMenu;
  let body;

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    menu = document.querySelector("#mouse-menu");
    dropDownMenu = document.getElementById("drop-down");
    body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    menu.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      dropDownMenu.style.display = "block";
      dropDownMenu.style.zIndex = "1";
      dropDownMenu.style.backgroundColor = "#fafafa";
    });

    dropDownMenu.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      dropDownMenu.style.display = "none";
    });

    menu.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      dropDownMenu.style.display = "none";
    });
  })
```

Comment: Премного благодарю!

Comment: Всё равно выдаёт такую же ошибку. Пытался нагуглить - безуспешно. Скажите, с чем это может быть связано ещё?